# "$.getScript @href" does not get the href from a button, only from an a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getscript

I am listening to a `button` and some `a` tags with this code:

```
$("#pagination_partial a, #order_sorting_partial a, #order_sorting_partial .organize-btn").bind("click", function() {
  $.getScript(this.href);
  history.pushState(null, "", this.href);
  return false;
});
```

The code is supposed to get the href from the clicked element, but as of now it is only getting the href from the `a` tags. When I click the `organize-btn` the code understands that the button is clicked, but it does not assign anything to `@href`.

What am I doing wrong? Here is the view file (HAML):

```
.row
    .span
        .btn-group
            %button.btn{:href => "/orders?view=#{@organize_mode}", :class => "organize-btn"}= t(".#{@organize_mode}")
            %button.btn.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown"}
                %span.caret
            %ul.dropdown-menu
                %li
                    %a{:href => "/orders?view=by_last_dispatch"}= t(".by_last_dispatch")
                %li
                    %a{:href => "/orders?view=by_first_dispatch"}= t(".by_first_dispatch")
```

Comment: Please post the compiled code, it's not a coffeescript-specific question. Also `button` elements don't have `href` attribute/property.

Comment: Umm... this isn't JavaScript...

Comment: Sorry, I have not inserted the javascript code instead of coffeescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The js object form of an anchor tag happens to have a href property, but don't confuse that as the same thing as having an href attribute on the DOM tag. In your markup you are adding an href attribute to your buttons, but those don't get automatically added to the js object like you are expecting. Assuming you want to continue to use an attribute named href, which I consider to be another off topic question, you will need to access that attribute from the DOM it self. With jQuery, you would want to replace your `this.href` with `$(this).attr("href")`